# How to change the FROM clause in SqlSoup / SqlAlchemy when doing a join?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlsoup

I would like to be able to do a join and get back specific fields from both tables in the result.

I am doing the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_, and_, desc
from sqlalchemy.ext.sqlsoup import SqlSoup

db = SqlSoup('mysql://localhost/mydb')

join = (db.table_B, db.table_B.id==db.table_A.id)

query = db.table_A.join(join)

for entry in query:
    print entry
```

For each result, the `entry` contains all of the fields for `table_B` and does not give me any of the fields for `table_A`. I realize that this happens by default because of ambiguous field names. However, I would like to manually specify the FROM clause to override this behavior. I have looked through the documentation and it appears to be non-trivial to change the FROM clause. I have not been able to do it successfully.

I would appreciate if somebody could suggest the correct modification that I could make to the above code to be able to get `entry.my_col` where `my_col` is a field in `table_A`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this out. The problem was that I was looking at SqlAlchemy documentation, when I really required SqlSoup documentation.

I found a nice example for doing joins here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/sqlsoup.html

And when I try doing it as described in the example I get all of the fields that I need back.